# Beamer and Boiboites

Tags: beamer

I am using `beamer` and `boiboites` for the definitions, theorems, …. In each theorem I have several items and use `\pause` for making the animation. The problem is that the box of the definition, theorem,… only appear at the end and not before the items. Why does it happen? I have tried several ways `\onlside<1>`, `\only<1>`, `\visible` .... no one works.

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) you are much more likely to get help if you include a full minimal example that shows this problem.

Comment: What's `boiboites`? I cannot find such a package on ctan https://www.ctan.org/search/?phrase=boiboites And how is it used?

Comment: Boiboites is this package: http://alexisfles.ch/en/latex/boites2.html

Comment: @BenjaminMcKay Are you sure? From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/367056/36296 I conclude there are different ones?

Comment: `xeboiboites`  looks like an alternative to `tcolorbox` but I am not sure that it provides as many features.

Answer (score 1):

This should work out of the box:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{xeboiboites}
  \newbreakabletheorem[
    small box style={draw=blue,fill=blue,line width=0.02cm, rounded corners},   
    big box style={fill=white,draw=blue,rounded corners,line width=0.02cm},
    size=1\textwidth, 
    headfont=\bfseries\large\color{white}
  ]{myproblem}{Problem}{myproblem}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{myproblem}
\begin{itemize}
\item test
\pause
\item test2
\end{itemize}
\end{myproblem}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(had to borrow some code from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/345713/36296 as this questions did not show how to use `xeboiboites`)

Comment: In case this does not work for you, please show us a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: @Ana Is your problem solved?