# Box around definitions in beamer

Tags: beamer

My latex code is give below :

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\title{Simple Beamer Class} 

\author{Sascha Frank} 

\date{\today} 

\begin{definition}

Two graphs $G=(V,E_1)$ and $H= (V,E_2)$ are said to be isomorphic if there exist a bijective map $\phi : V \mapsto V$ that preserve edges and non-edges

\end{definition}
}
```

I have seen this answer but its code is not working in a beamer class. I want boxes like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNIxc.jpg).

Comment: Can you go back to your previous questions and look if the answers solve your problems and accept them, if they do?

Answer (score 3):

There is already a box around, the colours are just not set.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercolor{block title}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg!75!black}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{parent=normal text,use=block title,bg=block title.bg!10!bg}

\begin{document}

\title{Simple Beamer Class} 

\author{Sascha Frank} 

\date{\today} 

\begin{frame}
\begin{definition}
Two graphs $G=(V,E_1)$ and $H= (V,E_2)$ are said to be isomorphic if there exist a bijective map $\phi : V \mapsto V$ that preserve edges and non-edges
\end{definition}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If the boxes should just be frames, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/400987/36296 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/367049/36296 could help.